# Request "Write External Storage" Permission for an Android 6 Native Process

Tags: android, process, permissions

Recently, I wrote a native executable program:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main() {
   FILE* f = fopen("/storage/<external_sdcard_root>/test.txt", "w+");
   fprintf(f, "hello");
   fclose(f);
   return 0;
}
```

I used NDK to compile it as "test" and put it to the res/raw folder of an Android project. I read the resource as a stream at runtime and write it to application data dir; then grant it executable permission. In my MainActivity, it requests write permission at the beginning when activity init as following: https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html; then the activity run `Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmd) /* cmd=["/path/to/datadir/test"] */` to start `test` process but it fails to create a file to my external storage. it works when I change the file path to my internal storage.

Can someone point out what should I do to grant the permission to the `test` process to get able to write files to the external storage? Thanks!